# Angular to SAML getting CORS

Tags: angularjs, cors, saml

I am using passport-saml to connect my angular application with my enterprise id service.

I am able to successfully call http://example.com/#/ and my webpage loads with a login button. The login button generates a failed CORS request.

```
$scope.signIn = function() {
    $http.get('http://example.com/auth')
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('ERROR');
             console.log(data);
        });
};
```

However, if I visit http://example.com/auth first and then go to http://example.com/#/ I do not get a CORS request and am able to get the object I need.

Can anyone help me understand why I cannot get the SAML object into my angular application from the code above?

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/auth');
```

your code:

```
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/auth');
$scope.signIn = function() {
    $http.get($scope.url)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('ERROR');
             console.log(data);
        });
};
```